# Search and sort in Grails/HQL by matching strings of search list

Tags: hibernate, grails, hql

I have a class of students

```
class StudentClass {
  String name
  static hasMany = [students: Student]
}
```

and the Student

```
class Student {
  String name
}
```

the Student can be in as many classes as he wants.

How can i write a query based on a list of student names e.g. ['Tom', 'Angelika', 'Timmy']
that gives me a list of all StudentClass objects in which students lists every student from the search list was existing.

And in advance what i really want to do: get a list of classes where at least one name from the search list is in the studends list and sort this list by the amount of students from the search list, that are in that list.

I'm sitting at that problem quite a long time now :/ I dont know if this should be done by using HQL. Any suggestion would be nice

**Edit**:
so here's an example what i want to get as query result for following objects saved in the database (for an easier example i just use the name of the students instead of the student object with name attribute)

```
StudentClass(name: 'Physics', students: ['Timmy', 'Herbert', 'Christian', 'Martha'])
StudentClass(name: 'Economics', students: ['Franz', 'Paul', 'Joseph'])
StudentClass(name: 'Sports', students: ['Timmy', 'Angelika', 'Christian', 'Jasmine'])
StudentClass(name: 'Math', students: ['Tom', 'Emelie', 'Angelika', 'Timmy'])
```

these 4 studen classes are persistent in the database.

now i want to query all the student classes that contain at least on of the students given in a list. This search-list could e.g. contain ['Tom', 'Angelika', 'Timmy']. In this case the result should be ordered by the how many students of the search-list are actually in that class:

1. Math - all 3 of them are in that class
2. Sports - 2 studens of the search list are in sports class
3. Physics - 1 student is in the physics class

the economics class chould not be returned since non of the studends from the search-list is in that class.

i read the whole documentation on [Hibernate Documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html) and i think 'some' and 'elements' could help me here but my problem is the sorting and having a variable number of search words.

Comment: You are looking for 2 different things: 1. You need all the students in the search should be in a class. 2. You need at least one student in the search list to be in a class. Individually each can be achieved in two different approach, which one are you interested more, 2 or 1?

Comment: hey, you're right but i thought that problem 1 would somehow lead to the solution of problem 2. actually i want to solve problem 2 with the additional sorting based on how many students from the search-list are in that class

Comment: I'm having trouble following this. Can you provide sample data with examples of what you want returned? This particularly makes no sense to me: "students lists every student from the search list was existing"

Comment: yep, updated it. sorry for a maybe not so clear description of what i want. english is not my native language

Answer (score 0):

So to get a list of classes where the students contain the students in a given list.

Along with the list, give the count of the students that are in the given list.

```
StudentClass.executeQuery("select sc.name, count(s) from StudentClass sc join sc.students as s where s in (:students) group by sc.name order by 2 desc",[students: [student1, student2]])
```

Is that what you want?

This searches based on name instead of the object

```
StudentClass.executeQuery("select sc.name, count(s) from StudentClass sc join sc.students as s where s.name in (:students) group by sc.name order by 2 desc",[students: ['Tom', 'Angelika']])
```

If you don't care about getting the count back from the query you can do the following:

```
StudentClass.executeQuery("select sc.name from StudentClass sc join sc.students as s where s.name in (:students) group by sc.name order by count(s) desc",[students: ['Betty', 'Sue']])
```